# How do I hide the network name from the notification bar on Fairphone?

Tags: mobile-network, notification-bar, carriers, fairphone-4

I recently switched my phone carrier and the new one has a network with a pretty long name. It shows in the top left of the screen, in the status bar. Since the name is long, it pushes other notifications to the right and they get cropped (my phone has a notch for the front camera).

The best solution for me would be to limit the size of the mobile network name (using ellipsis `...` if it's too long), but it seems to not be possible. As a second-best solution, how can I hide the network name?

I use Android 12 on a Fairphone 4, so it's pretty close to stock Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Fairphone 4 (Android 12), the network name can be hidden in **Settings | Display | Other display controls**. You can toggle the setting **Network name** to control the visibility of the network name in the notification bar / status bar.

Please note however that this setting may be non standard according to comments. It may not be available on all phones.

[image: Network name setting screenshot]

Comment: On Android 13, that setting doesnt exist, so I  cant verify your answer to vote. If you included a screenshot of it  then everyone would know at a glance that this was the correct answer

Comment: @RohitGupta Thank you for the feedback, I included a screenshot. Your comment gets me slightly worried: I hope that configuring this setting will still be possible on Android 13.

Comment: @Demurgos Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Appreciate the self-Q&A, though looks like this is a customization done by Fairphone (/e/OS ?), not a common setting in Android. Just for the info, there's no such option on Google Pixel 3a (Android 12) and Samsung Galaxy M12 (Android 13).

Comment: Thank you for the precision. I assumed Fairphone did not apply any customization, but I am no expert. Thanks for editing the title to mention Fairphone explicitly; I also updated the answer to mention that it's not standard.